# Where to store user's media

Tags: django, architecture, webserver, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have a web-service google cloud. It consists of:

1. load balancer;
2. group of instances (django code);
3. sql service;

But I don't know where to store user's files. Should I use separate media server, or google cloud storage?

How do you usually solve such problems?

Answer (score 1):

Well it will depend on what is your scenario and your requirements.

If you want full ECM capaibility for your files like versioning, different renditions, security policies , metadata etc then some ECM vendors like Alfresco, Sharepoint (cloud or on premise) would be a solution.

If you only want to store the files and retrieve them and also with some metadata then using a File Storage, plain Cloud Storage like Google cloud, Dropbox or even an object storage like S3/Swift could be solution.

Object storage fares better when concurrency is higher and you have requirements for scalabalitiy .If performance is a concern then file storage will do better.